# Dynamic loading on modules from modules in requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, amd

I'm using requirejs and have an `app.js` that pulls in `framework.js` and initializes it and passes in settings and modules with their own settings. Problem is `$('[data-navigation]').navigation();` is triggering before the `navigation` module, which is a jQuery plugin, is ready. If I add around a 500ms delay it works.

```
require(['jquery-private', 'framework', 'navigation'],
function($, framework, navigation) {

    //==========
    // Initialize the framework core.
    //==========
    var core = framework.init({
        // Core settings.
        namespace: '',

        // Initialize modules.
        modules: {
            navigation: {
                openClass: 'open',
            },
        },
    });

    //==========
    // App logic.
    //==========
    $('[data-navigation]').navigation();
});
```

Here is how the modules are initialized. I think the problem is happning with this `require([moduleName], function(module) {}` running while the script continues on.

```
define(['jquery', 'matchmedia'], function($) {

    //==========
    // Core initialization object.
    //==========
    var init = function(customOptions) {


        //==========
        // Logic
        //==========


        //==========
        // Load a module with it's custom options.
        //==========
        function initModule(module, customOptions, coreObject) {
            // Get the previously defined module or the path to load it.
            var moduleName = (require.defined(module)) ? module : config.modulesDir + '/' + module;

            // Initialize the module.
            require([moduleName], function(module) {
                var returnObject = module.init(customOptions, coreObject);

                // Add to the loaded modules if not already present.
                if (settings.modules.indexOf(moduleName) < 0) {
                    settings.modules.push(moduleName);
                    settings.m[moduleName] = returnObject;
                }
            });

            return settings.m[moduleName];
        }


        //==========
        // Logic
        //==========


        //==========
        // Build the core object.
        //==========
        var core = {
            // Properties.
            // Methods.
        }


        //==========
        // Load the defined modules.
        //==========
        $.each(config.modules, function(index, value) {
            initModule(index, value, core);
        });


        //==========
        // Return the core object.
        //==========
        return core;
    }


    //==========
    // Return the initialization object.
    //==========
    return {
        init: init
    }
});
```

I've been at this for a while now. I'm pretty sure there is a solution, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. Any guidance is appreciated.

Here is a good chunk of the navigation module code if it helps.

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {

    //==========
    // Module initialization object.
    //==========
    var init = function(customOptions, core) {
        // Ensure customOptions is an object.
        var customOptions = typeof customOptions !== 'undefined' ? customOptions : {};
        // Get the custom selector or the modules default.
        var selector = typeof customOptions.selector !== 'undefined' ? customOptions.selector : '[' + core.space('data-navigation') + ']';


        //==========
        // Build the jQuery plugin.
        //==========
        $.fn.navigation = function(options) {

            //==========
            // Plugin code.
            //==========

        }


        //==========
        // Initialize the plugin.
        //
        // RUNNING THE PLUGIN FROM HERE DOES WORK, BUT I NEED IT TO WORK FROM THE APP.JS TOO!
        //
        //==========
        $(function() {
            if ($(selector).length > 0) {
                $(selector).navigation(customOptions);
            }
        });


        //==========
        // Return object for core.m.[module]
        //==========
        return {};
    }


    //==========
    // Return the module initialization object.
    //==========
    return {
        init: init
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey Cliff, the way you are setting things up seems to be cool. Any way to get in touch to share some ideas?

Comment: Sure, you can email me cliffascent at gmail

Answer (score 0):

In the specific sample above, the solution was to use `module = require('moduleName');` instead of `require([moduleName], function(module) {}`. Here is the new initModule function;

```
function initModule(moduleName, customOptions) {
    // Do not initiate modules that aren't already loaded.
    if (!require.defined(moduleName)) {
        console.log('Module "' + moduleName + '" is not loaded. Add the module to the app dependency list or use require([moduleName], function(module) { /* Use module here. */ });');
        return false;
    }

    // Require the module.
    module = require(moduleName);

    // Ensure a path is no longer in the name.
    moduleName = moduleName.substr(moduleName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    // Add the modules return to the core object.
    settings.m[moduleName] = module.init(customOptions, core);

    // Add to the loaded modules if not already present.
    if (settings.modules.indexOf(moduleName) < 0) {
        settings.modules.push(moduleName);
    }

    // Return the modules return.
    return settings.m[moduleName];
}
```

Only problem is this only works if my `app.js` pulls in the module in it's `require()` statement. It will still hit the same error if the module is not compiled into the main script file and instead is loaded dynamically. My solution was to just send a message to the console saying to use `require([moduleName], function(module) { /* Use module here. */ });` if the module isn't compile into the main script. I'm still seeking a better solution, but it's starting to seem this is inherit in dynamically loading modules.